# Resolving local files to IEditiorInput -Eclipse plugin debugger development

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

While implementing own debug framework ,extending provided eclipse debug platform , i have following concerns.

I am overriding getEditorInput,getEditorId methods of ISourcePresentation interface.
I want to know when we have a stackframe associated with a jar file (which is not in the workspace) ,what is the best approach to resolve it?(obviously i am trying to load that file in work-space-editor when application hits a breakpoint in it.)

i am receiving object of org.eclipse.debug.core.sourcelookup.containers.LocalFileStorage and i want to resolve it and return as IEditorInput.

```
public IEditorInput getEditorInput(Object element) {
    if (----) {
        -----;
    } else if (element instanceof  LocalFileStorage) {
        //**What to do here**?
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Eclipse JDT uses `org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.LocalFileStorageEditorInput` but that is an internal class so it is off limits. You will probably have to look at it and reproduce what it does.

Comment: In what way does the existing support for doing this fall short?

Comment: hi greg, where can i look at the relevant source code for that?

Comment: hi @nitind , if the file is in the workspace , we can simply do like this.   `return new FileEditorInput((IFile) obj);`  But since the file is not in the workspace we cannot cast it to IFile . So have to do some other approaches.